# Heatmap not working on FeatureLayer (ArcGIS JS API 4.8)

Tags: javascript, heatmap, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I tried my best but didn't get success to show heatmap on FeatureLayer with latest ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.8. My Code is located [here](https://jsfiddle.net/SiddharthMishra/eLg10whk/).
I used [HeatMapRenderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-renderers-HeatmapRenderer.html) to render the point on the map as the heat map. But somehow it is not working at all. I think I am missing something which would be an easy fix.

Putting JavaScript code which I think should have fix:

```
const renderer = {
    type: "heatmap",
    colorStops: [{
        color: "rgba(63, 40, 102, 0)",
        ratio: 0
      },
      {
        color: "#472b77",
        ratio: 0.083
      },
      {
        color: "#4e2d87",
        ratio: 0.166
      },
      {
        color: "#563098",
        ratio: 0.249
      },
      {
        color: "#5d32a8",
        ratio: 0.332
      },
      {
        color: "#6735be",
        ratio: 0.415
      },
      {
        color: "#7139d4",
        ratio: 0.498
      },
      {
        color: "#7b3ce9",
        ratio: 0.581
      },
      {
        color: "#853fff",
        ratio: 0.664
      },
      {
        color: "#a46fbf",
        ratio: 0.747
      },
      {
        color: "#c29f80",
        ratio: 0.830
      },
      {
        color: "#e0cf40",
        ratio: 0.913
      },
      {
        color: "#ffff00",
        ratio: 1
      }
    ],
    maxPixelIntensity: 10,
    minPixelIntensity: 0,
    blurRadius: 8.764705882352942
  };
  var point = {
    type: "point",
    longitude: -81.4230821,
    latitude: 28.3103877,
  };
  var markerSymbol = {
    type: "simple-marker",
    color: [226, 119, 40]
  };
  var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
    geometry: point,
    symbol: markerSymbol
  });
  let graphics = getGraphics(Graphic);
  graphics.push(pointGraphic);

  const layer = new FeatureLayer({
    title: "Magnitude 2.5+ earthquakes from the last week",
    copyright: "USGS Earthquakes",
    source: graphics,
    popupTemplate: template,
    attributionVisible: true,
    fields: [{
        name: "OBJECTID",
        alias: "OBJECTID",
        type: "oid"
      },
      {
        name: "id",
        alias: "id",
        type: "integer"
      }, {
        name: "agencyId",
        alias: "agencyId",
        type: "integer"
      },
      {
        name: "heat",
        alias: "heat",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        name: "latitude",
        alias: "latitude",
        type: "number"
      }, {
        name: "longitude",
        alias: "longitude",
        type: "number"
      }
    ],
    objectIdField: "OBJECTID",
    outFields: ["OBJECTID", "heat", "id", "longitude", "latitude", "agencyId"],
    geometryType: "point",
    opacity: 1,
    spatialReference: {
      wkid: 4326
    },
    renderer: renderer
  });
  const map = new Map({
    basemap: "gray",
    layers: [layer]
  });
```

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you do not define a target field for the HeatMapRenderer ([see example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-renderers-HeatmapRenderer.html)) I think you need to define that property i.e. `field: "heat"`. However changing this in the fiddle didn't seem to solve the problem so must be something else as well.

Comment: @BigGerman You are correct. I tried to add field the `field: "heat"` but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I raised the question with Esri GeoNet Community and they answered it quite quickly. You can find detailed answers [here](https://community.esri.com/message/794092-heatmap-renderer-is-not-working-with-featurelayer).
Below is the answer:

> Heatmap requires WebGL, which requires Feature Layer services that are hosted or 10.6.1+. Heatmap with a collection of graphics does not work at the moment.

They also answered on StackExchange Geographical Information System community. You can find the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293205/heatmap-not-working-on-featurelayer-arcgis-js-api-4-8). The answer is:

> The HeatmapRenderer only works with WebGL-enabled FeatureLayer, and at version 4.8 one of the limitations for WebGL-support is listed as:
>   Layers created from feature collections or client-side graphics are not supported. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#webgl-rendering
>   This limitation should hopefully go away at next release (version 4.9).

Comment: I work with 4.10 version and my heatmap not working. Is this feature still not working for `FeatureLayer` with `Graphic` as `source` or I do something wrong?